# Sqlzoo: Inner Join #5 Can I use contents from one table in another without joining it together?

Tags: mysql, sql

The question regards the task #5 from sqlzoo.net accessible on https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/Self_join

The task:

Execute the self join shown and observe that b.stop gives all the places you can get to from Craiglockhart, without changing routes. Change the query so that it shows the services from Craiglockhart to London Road.

```
SELECT a.company
     , a.num
     , a.stop
     , b.stop
  FROM route a 
  JOIN route b 
    ON a.company = b.company 
   AND a.num = b.num
 WHERE a.stop = 53
```

And my solution is:

```
    <pre>
    SELECT a.company, a.num, a.stop, b.stop
    FROM route a JOIN route b ON
      (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
    WHERE a.stop=(SELECT id FROM stops WHERE name='Craiglockhart')
    AND b.stop=(SELECT id FROM stops WHERE name='London Road')
    </pre>
```

And it works. Would it be considered a bad practice though?
Or should I go with it by joining the two tables (as it is told in task #6)?

```
    <pre>
    SELECT a.company, a.num, stopa.name, stopb.name
    FROM route a JOIN route b ON
      (a.company=b.company AND a.num=b.num)
      JOIN stops stopa ON (a.stop=stopa.id)
      JOIN stops stopb ON (b.stop=stopb.id)
    WHERE stopa.name='Craiglockhart'
    </pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

Incidentally, the question makes a (likely erroneous) assumption that the order of stops is irrelevant.

Good practice might look something like this:

```
SELECT ra.company
     , ra.num
     , ra.stop
     , rb.stop
  FROM stops a 
  JOIN route ra 
    ON ra.stop = a.id 
  JOIN route rb 
    ON rb.num = ra.num 
   AND rb.company = rb.company
  JOIN stops b 
    ON b.id = rb.stop 
 WHERE a.name = 'Craiglockhart' 
   AND b.name = 'London Road';
```